# Move Wordpress from Root to Subfolder

Tags: directory

The standard problem of moving the WP installation from the root into the `my_subdir` folder keeping the url `www.example.com`.

Regarding the article [Moving a Root install to its own directory, Method I (Without URL change)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory/)

- After Installing the wordpress in root folder, move EVERYTHING from root folder into subdirectory
- Create a `.htaccess` file in root folder, and put this content inside (just change `example.com` and `my_subdir`)

These instructions simply do not work. They are even inconsistent with the article [Moving Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)!

Do somebody have the **correct** instructions?

- Should i change the `siteurl` and `home` DB options?
- Should i change the original `.htaccess` created by WP when updating the Permalinks?
- Should i change the `index.php` last line to include the `my_subdir`?
- Can the hosting be messing something disabling the functionality of the `.htaccess` around?

Update: Both Method I and Method II keep failing at the last step of logging in back. I am following the exact steps, and no, something in the new version of WP is messing with the subfolder installation (what?).

Comment: Do you want to put WP in a sub directory but still be able to browse it without using that sub directory? If so, why?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to move WP into a subdirectory, but you want just the homepage to be at the root domain? WP is either in a subdirectory or not. If WP is your full website, it would be better to either leave it in the root directory or move it completely. When you move it completely you can create a redirect so that people who go to `www.example.com` go straight to `www.example.com/my_subdir` to view the site. Perhaps you could provide more information about why you are looking for this solution so we can understand better and offer more help.

Comment: I am just follow whe Method I guide, keeping the URL `www.example.com`, moving WP from Root into `my_subdir`

Comment: I agree with WebElaine, it is not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Forget about the articles and concentrate your question on what you're trying to do (as opposed to explaining within the context of possibly unrelated articles).

Comment: Ok, i am looking for moving the WP installation from the Root `public_http` into a `my_subdir` folder, and keeping the `www.example.com` original url. The motivation is to keep several WP installations, for different subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the instructions if we suppose that you intially installed your site into ROOT folder (in the link you [provided](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) it's the method called **Method II (With URL change)** ).

There are two important steps and between them your site may break but it's not an issue :

I) First you need to update the link in the settings of your site. But you only need to update the **WordPress Address (URL)** by adding the subdirectory at the end to make it like this `www.yoursite.com/subdir`.

Now your site can stop working but no worries.

II) Second move all your files to the subdir then copy .htaccess file and index.php file from subdir and put them into the root directory (copy them and **don't move them back** you need to have a copy in root and a copy in subdir).

Open index.php file you moved to root and make these changes :

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

become

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/subdir/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

---

After this we are done, now you simply need to login to your site and save permalink structure again (without doing any changes) to be sure the url rewriting is updated correctly.

NOTE that your new admin access will be : `www.yoursite.com/subdir/wp-admin.`

I also advice you to clear your cookies and cache after migration to avoid any issues.

Comment: I am following these steps each time but i only get an `OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND.` (in caps) message from WP each time i try to access `subdir/wp-admin`. So i cannot finish the process.

Comment: @hyprfrcb You did update the index.php ? and you cleared your cache/cookies ?

Comment: Yes. i just opened in another browser. Nothing

Comment: @hyprfrcb ok let's follow together and you will get the issue. So you updated the link before doing the file changes ? the right one ? and the site broke after ?

Comment: @hyprfrcb and did you change the index.php in the **root** folder ? and are you sure there is no typo ?

Comment: I will update i whole new wordpress installation and repeat the steps again.

Comment: @hyprfrcb i will be here, let me know if there is any issue

Comment: Something is missing!. Why i cannot run `http://www.example.com/main/wp-admin/install.php` if i install WP from the `public_html/main` folder? Is the hosting messing with something? Or WP is only made to run from the root??

Comment: @hyprfrcb why you want to run this ? you mean a new install ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68299/discussion-between-temani-afif-and-hyprfrcb).

Comment: I am not sure, but i think the cookies and cache step made this work. Though i am not totally sure which method worked (I or II)...

Comment: @hyprfrcb am pretty sure it's the II as the I doens't change the url and cookies are always impacted by url changing